# Reset button text after audio plays

Tags: javascript, audio, mp3, innerhtml, playback

I have a button that plays an audio file when you click `playAudio` with the text "PLAY VOICE AUDIO", and the text is changed to "PAUSE VOICE". It pauses if you click `playAudio` again(now with the text "PAUSE VOICE") when playing.

> I would like the button text to go back to the "PLAY VOICE AUDIO" once the audio file has finished playing.

Thanks for any help in advance!

```
<div class="center">
    <button id="playAudio">PLAY VOICE AUDIO</button>
</div>

<audio id="testAudio" hidden src="testaudioagainmp3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>    


<!-- Play/pause audio script -->
<script>
document.getElementById("playAudio").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('testAudio');
    if(this.className == 'is-playing') {
        this.className = "";
        this.innerHTML = "PLAY VOICE AUDIO"
        audio.pause();
    } else {
        this.className = "is-playing";
        this.innerHTML = "PAUSE VOICE";
        audio.play();
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var audio = document.getElementById('testAudio');
var btn = document.getElementById("playAudio");
audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
 btn.innerHTML = "PLAY VOICE AUDIO";
 btn.className = "";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently only have an event listener for clicks on your button `playAudio`. You need a second event listener for when the `audio` has ended playing. In this case it is simply the [`ended`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp) event, which you need to attach to your `audio` variable with `addEventListener`.

Below is the the code I would use.

```
// This part is just a refactored version of your current code.
var audio = document.getElementById('testAudio');
var playButton = document.getElementById('playAudio');
playButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(this.className == 'is-playing') {
        this.className = "";
        this.innerHTML = "PLAY VOICE AUDIO"
        audio.pause();
    } else {
        this.className = "is-playing";
        this.innerHTML = "PAUSE VOICE";
        audio.play();
    }
});

// This runs when the audio ends and will change the `playButton`'s text to be "PLAY VOICE AUDIO"
audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    playButton.innerHTML = 'PLAY VOICE AUDIO';
    playButton.className = '';
}
```

I would also suggest learning some ES6(the newest JavaScript version), but I have left the code as is.